# Does TDD apply well when developing an UI?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, tdd

What are your opinions and experiences regarding using TDD when developing an user interface?

I have been pondering about this question for some time now and just can't reach a final decision. We are about to start a Silverlight project, and I checked out the [Microsoft Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut/) with TDD in mind, but I am not sure how to apply the approach to UI-development in general - or to Silverlight in particular.

**EDIT:**
The question is about if it is practical thing to use TDD for UI-development, not about how to do separation of concerns.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Trying to test the exact placement of UI components is pointless. First because layout is subjective and should be "tested" by humans. Second, because as the UI changes you'll be constantly rewriting your tests.

Similarly, don't test the GUI components themselves, unless you're writing new components. Trust the framework to do its job.

Instead, you should be testing the behavior that underlies those components: the controllers and models that make up your application. Using TDD in this case drives you toward a separation of concerns, so that your model is truly a data management object and your controller is truly a behavior object, and neither of them are tightly coupled to the UI.

Answer (score 9):

I look at TDD from a UI perspective more from the bare acceptance criteria for the UI to pass. In some circles, this is being labeled as ATDD or Acceptance Test Driven Development.

Biggest over-engineering I have found in using TDD for UIs is when I got all excited about using automated tests to test look and feel issues. My advice: don't! Focus on testing the behavior: this click produces these events, this data is available or displayed (but not how it's displayed). Look and Feel really is the domain of your independent testing team.

The key is to focus your energy on "High Value Add" activities. Automated style tests are more of a debt (keeping them up to date) than a value add.

Answer (score 5):

If you separate you logic from the actual GUI code, you can easily use TDD to build the logic and it will be a lot easier to build another interface on top of your logic as well, if you ever need that.

Comment: Yes, that is needed - but was it practical to use TDD in the first place?
In Silverlight the client is usually quite thin so the only thing that would need to be tested are user interaction events and that the data gets bound correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to Microsoft Silverlight, but I never use TDD for any kind of layout issues, just is not worth the time. What works well is using Unit Testing for checking any kind of wiring, validation and UI logic that you implemented. Most systems provide you with programmatic access to the actions the user takes, you can use these to assert that your expectations are correctly met. E.g. calling the click() method on a button should execute what ever code you intended. Selecting an item in a list view changes all the UI elements content to this items properties ...

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit, here's a little more detail about how we do it on my current team. I'm doing Java with GWT, so the application to Silverlight might be a bit off.

Requirement or bug comes in to the developer. If there is a UI change (L&F) we do a quick mock up of the UI change and send it over to the product owner for approval. While we are waiting on that, we start the TDD process.

We start with at least on of either a Web test (using Selenium to drive user clicks in a browser), *or* a "headless" functional test using Concordion, FiT or something like it. Once that's done and failing, we have a high level vision of where to attack the underlying services in order to make the system work right.

Next step is to dig down and write some failing unit and integration tests (I think of unit tests as stand-alone, no dependencies, no data, etc. Integration tests are fully wired tests that read/write to the database, etc.)

Then, I make it work from bottom up. Sounds like your TDD background will let you extrapolate the benefits here. Refactor on the way up as well....

Answer (score 2):

I think [this blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/21/the-tests-has-no-value-by-themselves-my-most-successful.aspx) by Ayende Rahien answers my question nicely using a pragmatic and sound approach. Here are a few quotes from the post:

> Testing UI, for example, is a common
>   place where it is just not worth the
>   time and effort.
>
> ...
>
> Code quality, flexibility and the
>   ability to change are other things
>   that are often attributed to tests.
>   They certainly help, but they are by
>   no mean the only (or even the best)
>   way to approach that.

Tests should only be used when they add value to the project, without becoming the primary focus. I am finally quite certain that using test-driven development for the UI can quickly become the source of much work that is simply not worth it.

Note that it seems the post is mainly about testing AFTER things have been built, not BEFORE (as in TDD) - but I think the following golden rule still applies: *The most important things deserve the greatest effort, and less important things deserve less effort.* Having a unit-tested UI is often not THAT important, and as Ayende writes, the benefit of using TDD as development model is probably not so great - especially when you think of that developing an UI is normally a top-down process.

Answer (score 1):

GUIs by their very nature are difficult to test, so as Brian Rasmussen suggests keep the dialog box code separate from the the GUI code.

This is the [Humble Dialog Box Pattern](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf).

For example, you may have a dialog box where details (e.g. credit card number) are input and you need to verify them. For this case you would put the code that checks the credit card number with the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) into a separate object which you test. (The algorithm in question just tests if the number is plausible - it's designed for checking for transcription errors.)

Answer (score 1):

At my workplace we use TDD and we actually unit test our UI code (for a web application) thanks to [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)'s [WicketTester](http://www.ddpoker.com/javadoc/wicket/1.4-m2/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/WicketTester.html) but it's not testing that some descriptive label is before a text field or something like that, instead we test that hierarchy of the components is somewhat correct ("*label is in the same subset as text field*") and the components are what they're supposed to be ("*this label really is a label*").

Like others have already said, it's up to the real person to determine how those components are placed on the UI, not the programmer, especially since programmers have a tendency of doing all-in-one/obscure command line tools instead of UIs which are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Test-Driven Development lends itself more to developing code than for developing user-interfaces. There are a few different ways in which TDD is performed, but the preferred way of true TDD is to write your tests first, then write the code to pass the tests. This is done iteratively throughout development.

Personally, I'm unsure of how you would go about performing TDD for UI's; however, the team that I am on performs automated simulation tests of our UIs. Basically, we have a suite of simulations that are run every hour on the most recent build of the application. These tests perform common actions and verify that certain elements, phrases, dialogs, etc, etc, properly occur based on, say, a set of use cases.

Of course, this does have its disadvantages. The downside to this is that the simulations are locked into the code representing the case. It leaves little room for variance and is basically saying that it expects the user to do **exactly** this behavior with respect to this feature.

Some testing is better than no testing, but it could be better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use TDD with great effect for GUI testing of web apps.

When testing GUI's you typically use stub/fake data that lets you test all the different state changes in your gui. You must separate your business logic from your gui, because in this case you will want to mock out your business logic.

This is really neat for catching those things the testers always forget clicking at; they get test blindness too !