# Can i use TDD in android developing process?

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd

I am a newbie to android. And feels like TDD can reduce developing time a lot. But after learning android's junit test framework, find it a bit difficult to achieve the goal that write test before coding. Especially when i want to test module like adapters, views and databases. So i wonder it's because i am not familiar with android test framework enough or android is not suitable for TDD.

Comment: Read these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362671/does-tdd-apply-well-when-developing-an-ui

Comment: I found it very hard to using TDD in view layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.. :-) In general TDD approach can be used for developing Android apps too. But not always worth.

It sometimes needs more effort, so you should consider the pros and cons carefully. I think you should not force to do every little part of your development process to be test-driven, but consider using it every time before you start typing. I prefer mixing TDD with test-last approach.

Comment: I think TDD is more suitable for model test. It will become more useful when testing a data module. But when it comes to UI test, it can't do much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using robolectric https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric
and here is sample https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample